# Comments in angular2

Tags: angular, comments

Does multiline comments i.e /* ... */ have issues in angular? I was trying out routing from the angular.io [guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html). In one of the routing module file I tried to modify the file with some of my changes like this

```
import { NgModule }             from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { CrisisListComponent1 }  from './crisis-list1.component';
import { HeroListComponent1 }    from './hero-list1.component';
/*  import { CrisisListComponent }  from './crisis-list.component';
    import { HeroListComponent }    from './hero-list.component';    */

 const appRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisListComponent1 },
      { path: 'heroes', component: HeroListComponent1 }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

This was throwing out the following error

```
localhost/:17 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:56301/traceur
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:56301/traceur
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:56301/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:29)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:56301/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:35)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:56301/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:56301/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:33)
    Error loading http://localhost:56301/traceur
    Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:56301/app/app-routing.module.js
    Error loading http://localhost:56301/app/app-routing.module.js as "./app-routing.module" from http://localhost:56301/app/app.module.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:56301/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:698:29)
        at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:56301/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:265:35)
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:56301/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:154:47)
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:56301/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:335:33)
    Error loading http://localhost:56301/traceur
    Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:56301/app/app-routing.module.js
    Error loading http://localhost:56301/app/app-routing.module.js as "./app-routing.module" from http://localhost:56301/app/app.module.js
```

After failing in all sorts of things in trying to figure and fix the error. I changed the multiline comment to single line comment like below and it worked!!!

```
// import { CrisisListComponent }  from './crisis-list.component';
// import { HeroListComponent }    from './hero-list.component';
```

But multiline comments in other sections of the code works perfectly fine. Its just to this part that it failed. Have i missed or broken something by using the multiline comment there. This just beats me am trying to learn angular2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with `SystemJS`. If you change your import statement to this:

```
/*  import { CrisisListComponent }  from './crisis-list.component';
 h  import { HeroListComponent }    from './hero-list.component';    */
```

It will work fine with the `h` in front of the `import`. Apparently if you put anything besides a white space in front of it, `SystemJS` won't pick it up. But because in your example there is nothing in front of the bottom `import`, it will think that it has to import that. Because the import statement is in `ES6` format, it will try to load `traceur` to transpile it in runtime. But obviously, you do not have that node_module installed, and no reference to it in your systemjs mapping.

I wouldn't worry too much about it, but if you want, you can file a bug report at systemjs :)

Comment: Oh ok thank you. Have filed a bug as you have advised. It might help others some debugging time. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12967